# VPS in CentOS7, run Files JAVA on start my vps

Tags: linux, centos7

my vps in centos 7 ,
I have applications developed in java, 3 files .jar .
I need to run this files when my vps start or log-in, like example "java -jar file-name"
how i can run that file like service

i have the second question is, 
what is the file in centos that has the list of services that run when you start centos.
For edit that file and add my jar. files

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The second questions:

CentOS uses systemd to start system-wide or user-defined services. You can use `systemctl` to find out. For example, checking out the SSH server daemon, we can do:

```sh
[user1@centos Good]$ systemctl | grep ssh
sshd.service                       loaded active running   OpenSSH server daemon
```

You can write your own `.service` file and put it under one of the following directories to make your java program run like a service.

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/
/lib/systemd/system/
```

To know more about `systemd` and `.service` file, you can check [CentOS / RHEL 7 : Beginners guide to systemd](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-beginners-guide-to-systemd/)

---

edit: 2019-11-13 18:53:47

//java_program.service

```
[Unit]
Description=java_program


[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /root/folder/name.jar
RestartSec=5
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Place `java_program.service` at path `/usr/lib/systemd/system/java_program.service`

Run command:

```sh
sudo systemctl enable java_program
sudo systemctl start java_program
```

Comment: ty for the comment , like this? ... example: "/root/folder/name.jar java -jar  " ? that in the file name.server , that is the format?

Comment: fixed , ty for the answer !!